# Single directional (Height only) self sizing UI components preview

Tags: xcode, swiftui, preview

I have a `UITableViewCell` containing a simple `UIStackView` and 2 `UILabel`s (**So it is from `UIKit`**, NOT native SwiftUI) that should have a static width and dynamic height. How can I have a preview for this without need to see the actual phone size?

**Note 1**: `.sizeThatFits` will put all the weight on the `width` and there will be no multiline `label`s

[image: sizeThatFits]

**Note 2**: `.device` is showing extra useless empty spaces of the main view of the screen.

[image: device]

**Note 3**: `.fixed(width:height:)` is not prefered, because it will have less space or extra useless space as our needs.

**Note 4**: Need something like this: (For `UIStackView`)
[image]

---

## DEMO

```
struct UILabelPorted: UIViewRepresentable {
    var configuration = { (view: UILabel) in }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UILabel {
        let uiView = UIViewType()
        uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
        return uiView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) { configuration(uiView) }
}

struct UILabel_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UILabelPorted {
            $0.text = "This label should have multiple lines like it is in a UITableView cell."
        }
        .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear where is the problem, but you need something like

```
ContentView()
    .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 414, height: 300))
```

Comment: Combination of Fixed width and dynamic height.

Comment: Demo added for more clarification.